# Ascii string of bytes packed into bitmap/bitstring back to string?

Tags: python, string, bitmap, bitstring

I have a string that is packed such that each character was originally an unsigned byte but is stored as 7 bits and then packed into an unsigned byte array. I'm trying to find a quick way to unpack this string in Python but the function I wrote that uses the bitstring module works well but is very slow. It seems like something like this should not be so slow but I'm probably doing it very inefficiently...

This seems like something that is probably trivial but I just don't know what to use, maybe there is already a function that will unpack the string?

```
from bitstring import BitArray

def unpackString(raw):
    msg = ''

    bits = BitArray(bytes=raw)
    mask = BitArray('0b01111111')

    i = 0
    while 1:
        try:
            iByte = (bits[i:i + 8] & mask).int
            # value of 0 denotes a line break
            if iByte == 0:
                msg += '\n'
            elif iByte >= 32 and iByte <= 126:
                msg += chr(iByte)
            i += 7
        except:
            break

    return msg
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data so that we can be sure we give you working solutions?

Comment: Sure, an example of the raw data is at: http://files.eas.cornell.edu/~mjs472/rawbytes.bin

Comment: Also, the data is for a weather string as defined by NWS. It should look something like "<NoWx>...<NoAttr>" when unpacked.

Comment: Don't have time to write the code now, but what you'd probably want to do is to iterate the bytes, converting every two consecutive bytes into a word (yes, with overlapping bytes), shifting as needed, then masking. This should is speed it up significantly.

Comment: Here, your function applied to your raw data sample (method: `unpackString(open("rawbytes.bin", "rb").read())`) returns `'\n\n \n\n\n,\n\n\n\n\n\n\n<None>\nSC.Y\nWS.W\nWS.A\n'` -- are you sure this is correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The important bits are the SC.Y WS.W and WS.A which denote weather conditions. I was wrong at what was contained in the binary string in my first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out, as your solution seems to ignore the first bit of data. Given the input byte of 129 (`0b10000001`) I would expect to see `64 '1000000'` printed by the following, but your code produces `1 '0000001'` -- ignoring the first bit.

```
bs = b'\x81' # one byte string, whose value is 129 (0x81)
arr = BitArray(bs)
mask = BitArray('0b01111111')
byte = (arr[0:8] & mask).int
print(byte, repr("{:07b}".format(byte)))
```

Simplest solution would be to modify your solution to use `bitstring.ConstBitStream` -- I got an order of magnitude speed increase with the following.

```
from bitstring import ConstBitStream
def unpack_bitstream(raw):
    num_bytes, remainder = divmod(len(raw) * 8 - 1, 7)
    bitstream = ConstBitStream(bytes=raw, offset=1) # use offset to ignore leading bit
    msg = b''
    for _ in range(num_bytes):
        byte = bitstream.read("uint:7")
        if not byte:
            msg += b'\n'
        elif 32 <= byte <= 126:
            msg += bytes((byte,))
            # msg += chr(byte) # python 2
    return msg
```

However, this can be done quite easily using only the standard library. This makes the solution more portable and, in the instances I tried, faster by another order of magnitude (I didn't try the cythonised version of `bitstring`).

```
def unpack_bytes(raw, zero_replacement=ord("\n")):
    # use - 1 to ignore leading bit
    num_bytes, remainder = divmod(len(raw) * 8 - 1, 7)

    i = int.from_bytes(raw, byteorder="big")
    # i = int(raw.encode("hex"), 16) # python 2
    if remainder:
        # remainder means there are unused trailing bits, so remove these
        i >>= remainder

    msg = []
    for _ in range(num_bytes):
        byte = i & 127
        if not byte:
            msg.append(zero_replacement)
        elif 32 <= byte <= 126:
            msg.append(byte)
        i >>= 7
    msg.reverse()

    return bytes(msg)
    # return b"".join(chr(c) for c in msg) # python 2
```

I've used python 3 to create these methods. If you're using python 2 then there are a number of adjustments you'll need to make. I've added these as comments after the line they are intended to replace and marked them `python 2`.

Comment: I like your unpack_bytes solution but the int.from_bytes doesn't work in python 2.7 either. Your ConstBitStream solution works great though.

Comment: Added a way of turning a byte string into an integer for python 2. Still just as competitive.